# How do I create a binary search algorithm that works with strings in an array?

Tags: c#, search, binary-search

I'm trying to get a binary search working for strings in an array but cant seem to get it to work. This is what I have to start with. (This is for numbers but I cannot find ANY examples of a binary string search anywhere).

```
        private void ButtonBinary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = arraySize - 1;
            if (!(Int32.TryParse(TextBoxSearch.Text)))
            {
                TextBoxMessage.Text = "You must enter an integer";
                return;
            }
            while (min <= max)
            {
                int mid = (min + max) / 2;
                if (target == integerArray[mid])
                {
                    TextBoxMessage.Text = target + " Found at index " + mid + 
                        ".";
                    return;
                }
                else if (integerArray[mid] >= target)
                {
                    max = mid - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    min = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            TextBoxMessage.Text = "Not Found, try again.";
        }
```

Comment: Why not using standard `int index = Array.BinarySearch(integerArray);`? If `index < 0`, the value is not found

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I've been specifically asked to not use Binary.Search, : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key component of a binary search is that you are using an **ordered** set of data to search through. It relies on the concept that if (for example) `x > myArray[10]`, that this inherently means that `x` is bigger than `myArray[0]` to `myArray[9]` as well.

The core logic of a binary search is this:

```
while (/*we are looking in a non-zero-length range*/)
{
    // find the middle point of the current range
    int mid = (min + max) / 2;

    if (/* match found */)
    {
        // search concluded, we found it!
    }
    else if (/* searched value is smaller than middle point */)
    {
        // do a search in the lower half of the range
    }
    else /* searched value is larger than middle */
    {
        // do a search in the upper half of the range
    }
}

// if we get here, and the search did not conclude, then it must not have existed
```

Notice how none of this logic really cares what data type we're working with. The only thing that it cares about is that:

1. The array of values to search is ordered
2. The values we're working with can be compared (i.e. `a < b`)

So, if you want to use strings instead of ints, all you have to do is:

1. Make sure your array is ordered alphabetically

This one isn't too hard:

```
string[] myOrderedArray = myUnorderedArray
                              .OrderBy(x => x)
                              .ToArray();
```

2. Be able to find out the alphabetical order of two strings  (i.e. `"abc" < "bcd"`)

If you google "C# compare strings", you'll easily find the [String.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-5.0) method, which does exactly that.

```
var compareResult = String.Compare(myFirstString, mySecondString);

if(compareResult < 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Alphabetical order: myFirstString before mySecondString");
else if(compareResult > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Alphabetical order: mySecondString before myFirstString");
```

Notice how very similar this is to your current `if else` logic.

---

> @DmitryBychenko I've been specifically asked to not use Binary.Search, : ( – LaggyAu

Because I get the suspicion that this is homework, or at least a challenge that was given to you specifically for learning purposes, I have intentionally chosen to not write the code for you. I leave the composing of the above information into working code as an exercise to you.

Comment: It is for learning purposes, but if I am are not taught how to do something, how are I meant to learn it? The purpose of asking for help is to get help, and learn from it.

Comment: @LaggyAu: The ability to write working code comes from the experience of trying to write working code. There is no shortcut here. I helped you with the analytical part of the challenge, but writing the code is something you're going to have to do on your own if you are to learn how to do it. Based on the code you presented, you are well capable of writing the needed code to do a string-based binary search.

Comment: I have tried, i chose to not include the code I have written because it contained a lot of method calling that would not make sense, I have been able to get a lot of it working just some things I couldn't. I appreciate the fact that you are trying to help me learn, but doing this does nothing but waste my time.

Comment: @LaggyAu: You're not seeing the wood for the trees. The core skill of software development is breaking problems down into smaller problems. I answered the question you asked. If you have other problems, you need to specifically address those, break them down, see if you can solve the smaller problem, and if not, ask a specific targeted question about that problem. If people give you the answer before you even managed to explain the precise problem, then you haven't learned the core skill of software development. There are no shortcuts to writing code. It's a matter of doing it until it works.

Comment: @LaggyAu: In other words, you asked how to write a string-based binary search algorithm, and I answered that question. If you have a problem related to writing code, *which is not trivially googleable*, then you can post a new question here, asking about that specific problem. As far as I'm aware, the only bits I left as an exercise to you are rudimentary syntax things such as using variables and `if`/`while` structures. If you're being given a challenge about binary search algorithms, you should already understand basic syntax. And if you don't already, you need the hands-on practice anyway.

Comment: I have been able to get the program working, adding final touches, if your curious how it went, I started with your structure then moved onto something closer to what I was using beforehand and was able to get it working. If you want to see the code or the whole program I'm more than happy to show you.

Comment: @LaggyAu: Happy to see you got it working! Well done :)